# The Android Gradle plugin supports only Kotlin Gradle plugin version 1.3.10 and higher

Tags: android, flutter, kotlin

- What went wrong:
  The Android Gradle plugin supports only Kotlin Gradle plugin version 1.3.10 and higher.
  The following dependencies do not satisfy the required version:
  project ':drawerbehavior' -> org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.2.71
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 4s
Running Gradle task 'assembleRelease'...
Running Gradle task 'assembleRelease'... Done                       5.3s
Gradle task assembleRelease failed with exit code 1

```
android {
compileSdkVersion 28

sourceSets {
    main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
}

lintOptions {
    disable 'InvalidPackage'
}

defaultConfig {
    // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
    applicationId "com.example.sununigeriaflutter"
    minSdkVersion 16
    targetSdkVersion 28
    versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
    versionName flutterVersionName
    testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}

buildTypes {
    release {
        // TODO: Add your own signing config for the release build.
        // Signing with the debug keys for now, so `flutter run --release` works.
        signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
    }
}
```

}

flutter {
    source '../..'
}

```
dependencies {
implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.2.0'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'
```

}

Answer (score -1):

Your error itself gave you the solution. You need to upgrade kotlin-stdlib-jdk7 dependencies version in this line.

```
implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
```

Find where `$kotlin_version` is defined. Change it to latest version as defined on [Official Kotlin Release page](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/releases.html#release-details)

Comment: This does not work and current version of  ``$kotlin_version`` isn't it  1.6.10

Comment: Yes @ace it is now but 2 years back it was 1.3.61. Basically update your kotlin version to the latest.